# Possible to initialize an array after the declaration in C?

Tags: c, variable-declaration

Is there a way to declare a variable like this before actually initializing it?

```
    CGFloat components[8] = {
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.15
    };
```

I'd like it declared something like this (except this doesn't work):

```
    CGFloat components[8];
    components[8] = {
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.15
    };
```

Comment: @PaulTomblin: Not as the OP has suggested, but it is possible to assign to arrays in a few different ways.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You cannot assign to arrays so basically you cannot do what you propose but in C99 you can do this:

```
CGFloat *components;
components = (CGFloat [8]) {
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.15
};
```

the `( ){ }` operator is called the *compound literal* operator. It is a C99 feature.

Note that in this example `components` is declared as a pointer and not as an array.

Comment: This avoids the error alright but It does not populate the array. I am trying to use this idea in Quartz to set default values of two CGFloat arrays to hold color values and it,s not working.;  I initialize the pointer static CGFloat * color, then I try this approach and do color = (CGFloat[4]){1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0}; and then call CGContextSetFill(context, color) it does not draw. If I simply do static color[4]; then color[0] = 1.0; color[3] = 1.0 and repeat the fill call , it works as expected. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: this is off-topic, but does this also work with c++? It gives me an `error: taking address of temporary array`

Comment: @ArchLinuxTux Compound literals are not supported in C++ (some compilers support it as an extension).

Comment: @ouah but does it change the address of `components` or is it possible to use this to write an array at a specific address?

Answer (score 14):

If you wrap up your array in a struct, it becomes assignable.

```
typedef struct
{
    CGFloat c[8];
} Components;


// declare and initialise in one go:
Components comps = {
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.15
};


// declare and then assign:
Components comps;
comps = (Components){
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.15
};


// To access elements:
comps.c[3] = 0.04;
```

If you use this approach, you can also return `Components` structs from methods, which means you can create functions to initialise and assign to the struct, for example:

```
Components comps = SomeFunction(inputData);

DoSomethingWithComponents(comps);

comps = GetSomeOtherComps(moreInput);

// etc.
```

Comment: @ouah but does it change the address of `components` or is it possible to use this to write an array at a specific address?

Answer (score 0):

That notation for arrays and structs is valid only in initializations, so no.