# 2D Array Value Assign After Declaration in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, 2d, declaration

I know when we want to assign values to 2D arrays as we declare the array, we do this:

```
int myArray[2][4] = {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8}};
```

But how should I assign values "after" declaring it? I want to do something like this:

```
int myArray[2][4];

myArray = {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8}};
```

When I do it, the compiler gives error. Help please.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886375/possible-to-initialize-an-array-after-the-declaration-in-c

Comment: Plain arrays are not assignable, so you have to fill in each element individually. You could consider using a standard library container, such as `std::array`.

Comment: Can you use C++11 and `std::vector` instead?

Comment: I've used the array in my code too much. So I can't replace it with anything at all. :(

Comment: `Refactoring` is your friend and, if done carefully, can save you time as opposed to manually making the replacements from `myArray[2][4]` to `std::vector<std::vector<int> > myArray;`  If you are using an IDE that supports `refactoring` and `find and replace`, then you should be good to go.

Comment: @Mushy I would say the better replacement here is `std::array<std::array<int,4>,2>`. This keeps the elements in contiguous memory and has no overhead.

Comment: @juanchopanza How to create a 2D vector then? With 2 rows and 4 columns?

Comment: @juanchopanza nevermind, figured it out

Comment: OK, I added an example anyway.

Comment: @juanchopanza The OP: `But how should I assign values "after" declaring it?` `std::array` is fixed like built-in array and so no, you can't do what the OP desires.

Comment: @Mushy you can, as in my example.

Comment: @zakinster Actually, I just realized the question you point to has `C` label this is a `C++` question and thus the answers are actually different

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Since `C++03` doesn't provide any more alternatives than `C89` on this matter, the answers are only different if we include the `C++11` alternatives. The real question is "Does the `C++` tag includes `C++11` ?" If yes, then this answer is definitely not a duplicate.

Comment: @zakinster The `C++` tag does indeed cover `C++11`, although the answer should note that it is `C+11` specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `std::vector` then you can do this:

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector< std::vector<int> > arrV ;

    arrV = { {1,2,3,4}, {5,6,7,8} };
}
```

or using `std::array`:

```
#include <array>

int main()
{
    std::array<std::array<int,4>,2> arr ;

    arr =  {{  {{1,2,3,4 }}, {{5,6,7,8}}  }} ;
}
```

Note, the double set of braces in both the inner and outer set. This answer though only works in C++11.

Comment: Can I use it like arrV[1][2] to assign values later?