# Declaring an array outside and initializing using an initialize list

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I am having trouble initializing a 2D int array.
The structure of my program is:

```
int arr[2][2];
if(val==1)
 arr = {{1,1}, {2,2}};
else if (val==2)
 arr = {{3,3}, {4,4}};
...
...

int x = arr[1][1];
...
```

I am getting an error "Expression must be a modifiable lvalue"

Thanks.

Comment: What is the relevance of the 2D?

Comment: @ArchLinuxTux do you believe the accepted answer here is a duplicate of the answer of your question? I fail to see how they are duplicates. The accepted answer of using array<> is the right way to go about this and it was not part that answer.

Comment: @madu It's no duplicate, because the other answer is in C and the solution from C doesn't work for C++.

Comment: If someone needs to do this in C, [here is how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886375/possible-to-initialize-an-array-after-the-declaration-in-c) with this one: `char (*daytab)[3] = (char [][3]){{1, 31, 4}, {2, 31, 4}};` for multidimensional arrays.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your code, `arr = {{1,1}, {2,2}};` is **not** initialization. If you insist on the native array, I'm afraid you have to manually set each element.

However you can switch to use `std::array`, which gives what you want:

```
array<array<int, 2>, 2> arr;
if (val == 1)
    arr = { { { 1,1 }, { 2,2 } } };
else if (val == 2)
    arr = { { { 3,3 }, { 4,4 } } };

int x = arr[1][1];
```

Note the extra braces (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759757/multidimensional-stdarray)).

Comment: with c++14 extra-braces are not needed anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Initializing

```
int arr[2][2] = {{3,3}, {4,4}};
```

modifying

```
arr[0][0] = 3;
arr[0][1] = 3;
arr[1][0] = 4;
arr[1][1] = 4;
```

Comment: Thank you. This is not quiet possible because arr is actually a [10][11] array.

Comment: this is the way for `int` types, you're still able to loop and make things easier, or since you mentioned C++, things are more comfortable with its provided libraries.