# Initialization of array which is created before in C

Tags: c, arrays, initialization

```
int a[5] = {2,4,6,8,10}; // Works
```

But,

```
int a[5];
a = {2,4,6,8,10}; //Doesn't Work
```

Why?

Is there any other way in which I can initialize a array in a single go which is created before.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137671/declaring-and-initializing-arrays-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137671/declaring-and-initializing-arrays-in-c)

Comment: The first is an initialization, not an assignment.    The second attempts to assign an initializer to an array (as an executable assignment), which isn't supported in C.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886375/possible-to-initialize-an-array-after-the-declaration-in-c

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it myself, but since C99 you should be able to use a [*compound literal*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal) with [`memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy) to copy the data into the array:

```
memcpy(a, (int[5]){2,4,6,8,10}, sizeof a);
```